# Converting Unusual DateTime String to DateTime Object

Tags: c#, string, datetime, date-conversion

I'm working with a log file that is giving me a date string that looks like so:

```
09/Feb/2012:00:38:48
```

I've been looking at different pages online about converting dates such as the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), but none of them show a date quite like this one.

Do I need to manually reformat the string to look similar to:

```
2012-02-09T00:38:48.0000000
```

Or is there a way to have this actually converted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) to parse a string to a DateTime from any format you specify. There's a load of examples the bottom of this [MSDN ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx).

Comment: @MordecaiX7: You want MMM - see my example.

Comment: Use MMM which represents the shorthand month name as per your case. Check out the full reference for the options for formatting here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Ah I didn't realize I could tell the parser what format the date is in.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by AdaTheDev, [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) is the way forward here. As per the MSDN page on ["custom date and time format strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) you want MMM for the abbreviated month name.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        string text = "09/Feb/2012:00:38:48";
        DateTime value;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                   DateTimeStyles.None,
                                   out value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success! {0}", value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` - it doesn't look like you should use the current culture for example.

(Of course, you could use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) instead ;)